# Spring Data JPA findAll() nested json return some data with id only

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Data JPA with MySql to create REST API, in my data:
Project have a Set of Job - Job have a Set of Candidate - Candidate have one Employee.

When I use findAll() Project if an Employee is in a Candidate already the next json data of that Employee just have id of Employee not all data. I don't know why this happen.

This is my json all project:

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "BV1",
      "company": "FPT software",
      "teamsize": 2,
      "timestart": "2019-04-04",
      "timeend": "2020-04-13",
      "description": "dự án bệnh viện 1",
      "techskills": "Java, Jpa",
      "status": "On-going",
      "createBy": 1,
      "createDate": "2019-4-04",
      "modifyBy": 1,
      "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
      "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
      "jobs": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "description": "tester dự án bệnh viện 1",
          "role": "Open",
          "timestart": "2019-4-04",
          "timeend": "2020-04-04",
          "status": "Mockito",
          "createBy": 1,
          "createDate": "2019-4-04",
          "modifyBy": 1,
          "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
          "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
          "candidates": [],
          "matchedCertificates": [
            {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "TOEIC",
              "score": 900,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04"
            }
          ],
          "matchedLanguages": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "English",
              "level": 2,
              "lastused": 2019,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04"
            }
          ],
          "matchedTechSkills": []
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "description": "dev dự án bệnh viện 1",
          "role": "DEV1",
          "timestart": "2019-04-04",
          "timeend": "2020-04-04",
          "status": "Open",
          "createBy": 1,
          "createDate": "2019-4-04",
          "modifyBy": 1,
          "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
          "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
          "candidates": [],
          "matchedCertificates": [],
          "matchedLanguages": [],
          "matchedTechSkills": []
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "description": "pm dự án bệnh viện 1",
          "role": "PM",
          "timestart": "2019-04-04",
          "timeend": "2019-04-13",
          "status": "Open",
          "createBy": 1,
          "createDate": "2019-4-04",
          "modifyBy": 1,
          "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
          "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
          "candidates": [
            {
              "description": "pm dự án bệnh viện 1",
              "status": "Pending",
              "proexpid": 0,
              "roleid": 0,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
              "employee": {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "Ung Văn Khiêm",
                "gender": "Nam",
                "birthday": "1997-08-02",
                "position": "DEV",
                "department": "FA",
                "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteut anim id est laborum.",
                "email": "congtien.iuh@gmail.com",
                "cvstatus": "Pending",
                "avatar": "",
                "effort": 0,
                "lastLoad": "2019-03-19",
                "score": 0,
                "scoreTechSkill": 0,
                "scoreLanguage": 0,
                "scorecertificate": 0,
                "createBy": 2,
                "createDate": "2019-03-19",
                "modifyBy": 2,
                "modifyDate": "2019-03-19",
                "certificates": null,
                "languages": null,
                "educations": null,
                "projectExperiences": null
              },
              "job": 3
            },
            {
              "description": "pm dự án bệnh viện 1",
              "status": "Pending",
              "proexpid": 0,
              "roleid": 0,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
              "employee": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Nguyễn Thị Hồng",
                "gender": "Nam",
                "birthday": "1997-08-02",
                "position": "HR",
                "department": "FA",
                "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
                "email": "dnhat011@gmail.com",
                "cvstatus": "Approved",
                "avatar": "",
                "effort": 10,
                "lastLoad": "2019-03-19",
                "score": 0,
                "scoreTechSkill": 0,
                "scoreLanguage": 0,
                "scorecertificate": 0,
                "createBy": 1,
                "createDate": "2019-03-19",
                "modifyBy": 1,
                "modifyDate": "2019-03-19",
                "certificates": null,
                "languages": null,
                "educations": null,
                "projectExperiences": null
              },
              "job": 3
            }
          ],
          "matchedCertificates": [],
          "matchedLanguages": [],
          "matchedTechSkills": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Unit test",
              "level": 4,
              "experience": "",
              "lastused": 2019,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "description": "dev dự án bệnh viện 1",
          "role": "DEV1",
          "timestart": "2019-04-04",
          "timeend": "2019-04-17",
          "status": "Open",
          "createBy": 1,
          "createDate": "2019-4-04",
          "modifyBy": 1,
          "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
          "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
          "candidates": [
            {
              "description": "dev dự án bệnh viện 1",
              "status": "Pending",
              "proexpid": 0,
              "roleid": 0,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
              "employee": {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Ung Văn Khiêm",
                "gender": "Nam",
                "birthday": "1997-08-02",
                "position": "DEV",
                "department": "FSU1",
                "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteut anim id est laborum.",
                "email": "thanhhai97sd@gmail.com",
                "cvstatus": "Pending",
                "avatar": "",
                "effort": 0,
                "lastLoad": "2019-03-19",
                "score": 0,
                "scoreTechSkill": 0,
                "scoreLanguage": 0,
                "scorecertificate": 0,
                "createBy": 2,
                "createDate": "2019-03-19",
                "modifyBy": 2,
                "modifyDate": "2019-03-19",
                "certificates": null,
                "languages": null,
                "educations": null,
                "projectExperiences": null
              },
              "job": 1
            },
            {
              "description": "dev dự án bệnh viện 1",
              "status": "Pending",
              "proexpid": 0,
              "roleid": 0,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
              "employee": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Nguyễn Việt Hoàng",
                "gender": "Nam",
                "birthday": "1997-08-02",
                "position": "Admin",
                "department": "FA",
                "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut laborep ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in ariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
                "email": "phanchuan.23@gmail.com",
                "cvstatus": "Rejected",
                "avatar": "",
                "effort": 100,
                "lastLoad": "2019-03-19",
                "score": 0,
                "scoreTechSkill": 0,
                "scoreLanguage": 0,
                "scorecertificate": 0,
                "createBy": 1,
                "createDate": "2019-03-19",
                "modifyBy": 1,
                "modifyDate": "2019-03-19",
                "certificates": null,
                "languages": null,
                "educations": null,
                "projectExperiences": null
              },
              "job": 1
            },
            {
              "description": "dev dự án bệnh viện 1",
              "status": "Pending",
              "proexpid": 0,
              "roleid": 0,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
              "employee": {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Phan Minh Phụng",
                "gender": "Nam",
                "birthday": "1997-08-02",
                "position": "DEV",
                "department": "FA",
                "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptnt occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
                "email": "tranduy681996@gmail.com",
                "cvstatus": "Pending",
                "avatar": "",
                "effort": 70,
                "lastLoad": "2019-03-19",
                "score": 0,
                "scoreTechSkill": 0,
                "scoreLanguage": 0,
                "scorecertificate": 0,
                "createBy": 2,
                "createDate": "2019-03-19",
                "modifyBy": 2,
                "modifyDate": "2019-03-19",
                "certificates": null,
                "languages": null,
                "educations": null,
                "projectExperiences": null
              },
              "job": 1
            },
            {
              "description": null,
              "status": "Pending",
              "proexpid": 0,
              "roleid": 0,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-04-30",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-04-30",
              "lastLoad": "2019-04-30",
              "employee": 3,
              "job": 1
            }
          ],
          "matchedCertificates": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Java",
              "score": 0,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04"
            },
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "TOEIC",
              "score": 500,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04"
            }
          ],
          "matchedLanguages": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "English",
              "level": 3,
              "lastused": 2019,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04"
            }
          ],
          "matchedTechSkills": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Jpa",
              "level": 2,
              "experience": "",
              "lastused": 2019,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "BV2",
      "company": "FPT software",
      "teamsize": 4,
      "timestart": "2019-04-04",
      "timeend": "2020-04-13",
      "description": "dự án bệnh viện 2",
      "techskills": "C#",
      "status": "On-going",
      "createBy": 1,
      "createDate": "2019-4-04",
      "modifyBy": 1,
      "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
      "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
      "jobs": [
        {
          "id": 5,
          "description": "pm dự án bệnh viện 2",
          "role": "PM",
          "timestart": "2019-04-04",
          "timeend": "2019-04-13",
          "status": "Open",
          "createBy": 1,
          "createDate": "2019-4-04",
          "modifyBy": 1,
          "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
          "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
          "candidates": [
            {
              "description": "dev dự án bệnh viện 2",
              "status": "Pending",
              "proexpid": 0,
              "roleid": 0,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
              "employee": 4,
              "job": 5
            },
            {
              "description": "dev dự án bệnh viện 2",
              "status": "Pending",
              "proexpid": 0,
              "roleid": 0,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
              "employee": 3,
              "job": 5
            }
          ],
          "matchedCertificates": [],
          "matchedLanguages": [],
          "matchedTechSkills": []
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "description": "dev dự án bệnh viện 2",
          "role": "DEV1",
          "timestart": "2019-04-04",
          "timeend": "2020-04-04",
          "status": "Open",
          "createBy": 1,
          "createDate": "2019-4-04",
          "modifyBy": 1,
          "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
          "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
          "candidates": [
            {
              "description": "dev dự án bệnh viện 2",
              "status": "Pending",
              "proexpid": 0,
              "roleid": 0,
              "createBy": 1,
              "createDate": "2019-4-04",
              "modifyBy": 1,
              "modifyDate": "2019-4-04",
              "lastLoad": "2019-4-04",
              "employee": 3,
              "job": 6
            }
          ],
          "matchedCertificates": [],
          "matchedLanguages": [],
          "matchedTechSkills": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "message": "Get all project of company successfully!"
}
```

In project with id 1 - job with id 3 - I have employee with id 3 - employee data have all data I want.
But in  project with id 1 - job with id 1 - I have employee with id 3 again it just return the employee id, not whole employee json.

Comment: Probably because you have used https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html.

Comment: Thank you sir, it  fix my problem I have that on Employee class, after remove it, everything working good, have a good day sir.